# Can't use phone ase controller

Tags: testing, simulator, smartphone, airconsole

I want to test my airconsole game on a smartphone before publishing. The problem is, I can't connect it to the simulator.
If i try to connect (Chrome on Android) it says connecting, after a few seconds it shows the enter code screen but no input is possible. After about 30 seconds I get the message download the app for next time. (Screenshots attached)
Do you know where the problem is?
My files are hosted on a webserver, accessible from everywhere.

Kind regards

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

[image: Last Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `screen.html` and `controller.html` are accessible from all devices.

Let's assume you are running your local web server on http://192.168.0.2:8080/
Try to access http://192.168.0.2:8080/screen.html and http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html using a normal web browser on the device that doesn't work. It should display the screen/controller html.
If you can't access http://192.168.0.2:8080/controller.html from your phone, but from your computer, make sure you are in the same network and that your router does not have "Client Isolation" activated.
If you are testing with real smartphones, make sure you do not use http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/, because localhost is not your computer on the phone but the phone itself!

If you are still unable to connect your phone, you can use the ngrok tool to forward your local url. See our Ngrok Unity Guide for how to do this in the Unity Engine: https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/unity-ngrok

Comment: I don't know what did the trick but now it works (Maybee it was blocked from the hotel internet)